# S3 backup: bucket vs. volume

Tags: backup, encryption, amazon-s3, best-practices, disk-volume

I've inherited a project that has been pushing encrypted (GPG) DB backups via a backup script to an S3 bucket. That's all been well and good, but now that bootable EBS instances (where the project resides now) can have mounted S3 volumes, why not simply push to the volume? The script living on the server has the S3 credentials so I can't see where it is more secure to continue pushing to S3.

Also, is anyone can point me to a post or article about best practice for pushing backups off-site, I'd be much obliged.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

fused creates a S3 filesystem.. I have never used it but I heard it works great.

http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon

**Best practices?**

1. Don't lose your encryption private key, export it to something and put
   it in a safety deposit box.
2. Don't lose your private key.
3. Don't lose your private key.